# How to place functions in constructor in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I developed sample class as follows.

```
export class getPlatformShopIdByCode {

private shopCode:string;

constructor(shopCode:string){
    this.shopCode = shopCode;
     this.getPlatformShopIdByCode()
}

public  getPlatformShopIdByCode = async ():Promise<string |null> => {

    const queryResult = await 
            getRepository(Shop)
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .select("shop")
            .from(Shop,"shop")
            .where({shopCode:this.shopCode})
            .getOne()

    if(Boolean(queryResult!.platformFlag) !== true){
        return null;
    }
    return queryResult!.shopId;
    }
}
```

```
    const shopId = await new getPlatformShopIdByCode(this.Dto.getEvent().body.shopCode)
    
    await new FetchPricingPatternQuery()
        .fetch(
        shopId,
        true,
        this.Dto.getEvent().body.goodsCode,
        this.Dto.getEvent().body.tenantCode,
        this.Dto.getEvent().body.genreCode)
```

At `.fetch(shopId,----)` following error has occured.

`Argument of type 'getPlatformShopIdByCode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

I intended to execute `getPlatformShopIdByCode()` at constructor in `new` timing. what is the wrong point of that ?

`getPlatformShopIdByCode()` will return `string`. but actually it returned`getPlatformShopIdByCode` type.

If someone has opinion, will you please let me know , thanks.

Comment: Constructors cannot be `async` so `await new` makes no sense. Why are you using a class here anyway, with the same name as the function, instead of just a function?

Comment: As I am totally novice to this concept, it is just unfamiliar with object oriented design .All I knew was that classes should be split into small pieces. if there is more suitable design I would like to know.. thanks

Comment: Not everything needs to be an object. If it just _does_ a thing but not _is_ a thing, a function is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Heisenberg are you aware of the fact that class name is the same as the method name?

Comment: @AlanOmar I didn't think much of it, but is there something wrong..? Thanks